# Voltage rating of cables in marine applications

Tags: insulation-voltage, voltage-rating

I'm confused about voltage ratings of some special cable. Most cables for low voltage applications (<= 1kV) either have a single rating (e.g. 300V) or manufacturers give a different rating for AC and for DC.

However for marine cables one will find ratings like this: 0.6/1 (1.2) kV.
e.g. for this cable:
[Nexans MPRXCX](https://www.nexans.no/en/products/Ship-Marine-and-Offshore-Topside-Cables/Ship-Marine-Cables/Power---Control-cables/MPRXCX%C2%AE---27321.html)

I'm rather sure this is not the rating for AC and DC, because I found other marine cables which again have separate ratings for AC and DC, however again two values for each, which makes 4 ratings in total.

The manufacturers don't expose any explanation on their websites, at least I couldn't find any during almost one hour of search.

My guess is that the two (or even three) voltages describe ratings between two conductors and between one conductor and the outer. But if so, which one is the lower and which one is the higher?

The one in round brackets might be a peak voltage, but I can only guess.

I'm pretty sure there is some sort of rule with these ratings, because most manufacturers rate marine cables like that.

Comment: Assume all ratings are for AC RMS unless explicitly stated otherwise.

Comment: @winny That's right. AC RMS is always default for ratings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rated Voltage Uo/U (Um)

Uo, phase to earth
U, phase to phase
Um, maximum voltage

The cable is intended for Uo/U but there is headroom up to Um because most systems, such as mains grid, have 10% indefinite and 20% temporary voltage swell headroom.

Comment: Then I can't use a 0.6/1 kV cable for a 690V IT system, because in case of a persisting single insulation fault two of the phases will have a voltage of 690V to earth. Except if an insulation fault can be considered a temporary voltage swell.

Comment: @Ariser You're not supposed to continue operating with a fault. This should be found and fixed asap. Thus the cable is suitable (1.2kV). There aren't any better low voltage cables, next comes medium voltage.

Comment: Yes, I realized that. I found a 1.8/3 kV, but that is super rare.

Comment: Needless to say, your answer hits the nail on the spot and you gave the extra information I needed without having asked for it. Thank you!